# How to make the console theme dark,permanently

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

as the title says,my question is,is there any option that changes the theme of the console to dark one in phpmyadmin permanently?

I can't find the row in config.inc.php,but i guess there is a way to make it permanent from there.

Comment: https://github.com/theme1256/PMA-Dark-Metro-Theme

Comment: Thats a theme for the whole phpmyadmin  screen,what i need is just to make permanent setting for the dark theme on the console.